# Django : form validation in client side?

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-validation

I have two questions.

1. I made certain `view` accept `POST` request only through `ajax`(Not general `POST` request)

I'm using `Form` and realized that If I used `ajax`, I could not use django built-in form validation.

In this case, do I have to make my own validation for all fields in `javascript`?. I think that it is kinda time-consuming and redundant thing. Any alternatives?

2. Is it ok for `view` to accept only `ajax` POST request? I mean, I do something like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # return response
    else:
        # give HTTP404
```

Is it bad practice? Once the `view` accept `ajax` request, does it always accept general HTTP request, too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the form HTML in a separate template. When you submit with ajax, if the form is invalid, i.e. form.is_invalid() then instantiate the form with request.POST and render the template again. Then, return this rendered HTML back to your Ajax function and replace the existing form.

This will prevent having to fiddle around with JS a lot.